# Why does the degree symbol disrupt this FrameLabel?

Tags: plotting, bugs, formatting

This plot

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, FrameLabel -> {"x", "temperature / \[Degree]C"}, Frame -> True]
```

displays beautifully, but exporting to PDF

```
SystemOpen[Export[$TemporaryDirectory <> "plottest.pdf", %]]
```

results in the "C" flying into space:

[image]

Why is this? Is there a workaround to fix it?

Comment: It works fine for me, but you could try an `ImagePadding` option in the `Plot`.  Given that you don't have a `Frame -> True` are you sure this is exactly what you are doing?

Comment: @wxffles adjusting ImagePadding just reveals that the baseline of the "C" has been shifted. I must have Frame->True in my init.m somewhere. If you add Frame->True can you reproduce it?

Comment: The "C" is where you would expect it on mine (windows v9.0.1).

Comment: I'm in mma 10 on OS X 10.9.5. Can anyone else reproduce it?

Comment: I can reproduce the bug on MMA 10.0.0, OS X 10.10.3.  Exporting the file as EPS and then letting Preview convert to PDF produces the correct placement.

Comment: I can not reproduce it in MMA 10.1 on Win7-64bit

Comment: I'm provisionally tagging this as a bug, but more confirmation from Mac users would be welcome.

Comment: I can't check this example at the moment, but I'm on mac with 10.0.1 and I have had similar problems with non-standard typesetting in axes labels when exporting to pdfs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The workaround is to put an `\[InvisibleSpace]` between the degree symbol and the `C`.

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "temperature / \[Degree]\[InvisibleSpace]C"}, 
 Frame -> True]
```

Note that the `ImagePadding` isn't very good in this case, but the `C` does indeed have the right baseline.

Comment: I've found that the invisible space often works to fix this problem, so +1.